# concat multiple dataframe with index as loop variable

Tags: pandas, indexing

I create multiple dataframes by for loop and concat them, which works fine. But I need to include loop variable as index. I cant find a way to set loop variable as index

```
maindf=pd.DataFrame()
for i in ['20170724','20170725','20170726']:
    a=pd.read_csv("somecsv."+str(i))
    maindf = pd.concat(maindf,a,axis=0)
```

Expected OP for maindf:

```
         A  B  C
20170724 1  2  3
         4  5  6
         7  8  9
20170725 11 22 33
         44 55 66
         77 88 99
20170725 111 222 333
         444 555 666
         777 888 999
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need append all `DataFrame`s to `list` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys`, also for remove second level add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop`:

```
dfs = []
vals = ['20170724','20170725','20170726']
for i in vals:
    a=pd.read_csv("somecsv."+str(i))
    dfs.append(a)
maindf = pd.concat(dfs,keys=vals).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.concat` on a dictionary.

```
lst = ['20170724','20170725','20170726']
pd.concat({k: pd.read_csv('somecsv.{}'.format(i)) for k in lst})
```